# SCP - The authenticity of host can't be established (But cant enter anything at prompt)

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, scp

In windows 7 command prompt I enter:

```
scp -W Scp\password.txt -P 22 xxxx@xxxx.xxxx.com:/home/xxxx/xxxx/xxxxxxx.csv
```

After this I get the message:

> Do you want to trust this new host key and continue connecting? Please
>   type 'no','once', or 'always':

When I type any key, it just keeps repeating

> Please type 'no','once', or 'always':

Is there any idea how to fix this, something to put in the script? I have tried echo always and it does nothing to help

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Which kind of scp are you using? The one from Putty package?

Comment: I believe that is correct.

Comment: You shouldn't type a key, you should enter "yes" (without quotation)...

Comment: cant enter yes, always or anything. If i start to type  y e s  - It instantly asks the question again. Almost like any key is acting like a return key. Part of  display in command window is: 
The authenticity of host 'XXXXXXX (XX.XX.XX.XX)' cannot be established.
The fingerprint of the RSA key is:
MD5 Hex
  Lots_Of_hex_code
SHA1 XXX-XXXX
  -long string of letters-

Do you want to trust this new host key and continue connecting?
Please type 'no','once' or 'always':

Please type 'no','once' or 'always':

Please type 'no','once' or 'always':
(Above is what happens when i attempt type always)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when trying to upload my id_rsa.pub using Command Prompt. I used the same scp command in PowerShell instead and it allowed me to submit "yes" at that prompt (in your case, it would have been, "always" or "once"). It showed no text while I was typing it in.